# Why does Software always restart for upgrades?

Tags: software-center

In Ubuntu 20.04, upgrades via GNOME Software <strike>Software Center</strike> seem to require a restart for all package upgrades. Why is this?

I've used Linux for many years and usually upgrade via the command line or Synaptic. I pay attention to the GNOME Software for the BIOS upgrades (on Dell), which have historically been a pain. Having the GNOME Software recommend reboots, nearly daily, feels like a regression to Windows.

So, why does GNOME Software recommend reboots so often? Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Edit 3: A screenshot of the primary observation:
[image]

Edit 2: Thanks to @raj for helping to clarify. I meant GNOME Software, not the older and discontinued Software Center.

Edit 1: To be clearer, SC requires restart even when the the upgrades do NOT include the kernel or other core components.

Comment: It recommends reboot only after a kernel update.

Comment: In the list of upgrades you see, is there a kernel upgrade?

Comment: refers to server but the same principal apples https://linuxhandbook.com/system-restart-required-ubuntu/

Comment: I use the app **Software Updater**. It is light and fluffy and does not have this problem. It only asks for a reboot if there is a system update such as a new kernel.

Comment: There is this system of unattended upgrades, where updates are downloaded and installed when the system is shutdown, kind of Windows like. It is not that you are *required* immediately to reboot - it is only happening whenever you select to shut down the computer, and not if you keep the computer running.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm unable to duplicate this behavior. My Ubuntu Software application does not prompt me to reboot unnecessarily.

Comment: SC recommends restart for literally all changes. I expect restarts for kernel upgrades.  I'll take a screenshot and attach next time.

Comment: What is "Software Center"? Ubuntu 20.04 does not have such an application. It does have "Ubuntu Software", also known as "Snap Store", and - if you specifically installed it - "Software" (also known as "GNOME Software"). But none of them is responsible for system updates. There is a special application "Software Updater" for that. It pops up automatically when there are any updates to install and asks if you want to install them. Does not prompt for reboot until updates are for kernel or other critical components.

Comment: @raj Thanks for helping to clarify. I thought that Software Center (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Software_Center) evolved into Software, but I was mistaken.

Comment: FWIW: `/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs` - if it exists - tells which packages requested a reboot after updates. (in 20.04 at least).

Comment: But why do you use GNOME Software for updates, when Software Updater that I mentioned is installed by default, automatically notifies about updates whenever needed and does not prompt for reboot? I have both Snap Store and GNOME Software installed, and still use Software Updater for updates, because it just pops up by itself asking for update.

Comment: @raj Because it was not clear to me which to use or the scope/limitations of each. The software/system update space has changed several times over the years (witness my reference to Software Center), and I wasn't up-to-date with the landscape.  Your answer helped.

Comment: By the way, the gnome-software package description is "Software Center for GNOME", so I wasn't so crazy to think that was its name. :-/

Comment: I think the Software Updater was always present and always worked pretty much the same. I was using it in 10.04, I was using it in 18.04 (yes, I directly switched from 10.04 to 18.04, wasn't using any other releases in between), now I'm using it in 20.04.

Comment: After more digging, I now see that the ubuntu-software package is a translational package (i.e., empty) that depends on gnome-software. `apt info ubuntu-software` says "This is a transitional dummy package, it can be safely removed." after all this, they're essentially the same thing. update-manager is distinct. I'm just going to turn GNOME software notifications off and periodically check. The only reason I keep it around is for BIOS updates, which it handles nicely.